# JW Player in FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jwplayer

I am trying to get JW Player to work inside Fancy Box.  Fancy Box opens OK at the dimensions set below, but the video doesn't display (this is on a server). An example link that I'm using on a page (which is on the same level as the scripts and content diectories - the mp4 is in the content directory)

```
<a href='content/brat.mp4' class='video' data-width="600" data-height="345" title='me'>Robot</a>
```

and in the page:

```
    $(".video").fancybox({
    fitToView: false, // to show videos in their own size
    content: '<span></span>', // create temp content
    scrolling: 'no', // don't show scrolling bars in fancybox
    afterLoad: function () {
      // get dimensions from data attributes
      var $width = $(this.element).data('width'); 
      var $height = $(this.element).data('height');
      // replace temp content
      this.content = "<embed src='scripts/jwplayer/jwplayer.swf?file=" + this.href + "&autostart=true&amp;wmode=opaque' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='" + $width + "' height='" + $height + "'></embed>"; 
    }
  });
```

in scripts/jwplayer/ there is jwplayer.flash.swf, jwplayer.js and jwplayer.html5.js

[image]

Comment: I have always had a different approach to open videos with specific swf players, mostly using the `embed` method. If you are using fancybox v2.x check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429717/1055987 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/a/14326919/1055987 for samples of code.

Comment: Thanks JFK, I had seen those and played around but no luck.  I have edited my original question showing the code that I am now using from your second example.  Again, fancy box pops up, but no video.  I have also changed the link to suit as above.

Comment: notice that I am not using the `.click()` method in my examples ... and notice that you don't have `data-width` or `data-height` attributes in your link

Comment: Yep, just tried exactly the same and still no show...see edited question.

Comment: any chance to share a link to see the issue? ... I suspect is a path issue

Comment: your link targets to http://130.95.21.121/content/brat.mp4 and returns 404 error (not found) ... why you don't try an absolute path

Comment: ok, you found your video http://130.95.21.121/vpath/content/brat.mp4 so set `<a href='http://130.95.21.121/vpath/content/brat.mp4' class='video' data-width="600" data-height="345" title='me'>` (you had an unwanted `;`)

Comment: ... AND make sure that you have the right path for the jwplayer (it seems to have the same path issue)

Comment: Also, if I remove content: '<span></span>', // create temp content the video plays in a full screen with what seems to be jwplayer

Comment: Sorted...the problem was jwplayer 6.  I downloaded version 5 and all works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted...the problem was jwplayer 6. I downloaded version 5 and all works!

http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.3#js

Jeez...

Comment: This is because in JW6 you need to use jwplayer.js to embed the player. In your code above <embed> is being used, which won't work with JW6.

Comment: I have tried embedding with jwplayer.js using JW6 but can't get it to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846926/jwplayer-in-fancybox-not-playing-on-ipad-iphone

Comment: This is because you need to use our JS embedder in this case.