# jwplayer in fancybox not playing on ipad/iphone

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jwplayer

I'm using the following code but videos won't play with jwplayer inside fancybox on iOS (ipad/iphone)...works fine otherwise.  I appreciate that iOS doesn't handle flash, but I'm unsure of how to modify this code to provide for the html5 fallback...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jwplayer/html5/jwplayer.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".video_popup").fancybox({
    fitToView: false, // to show videos in their own size
    content: '<span></span>', // create temp content
    scrolling: 'no', // don't show scrolling bars in fancybox
    afterLoad: function () {
      // get dimensions from data attributes
      var $width = $(this.element).data('width'); 
      var $height = $(this.element).data('height');
      // replace temp content
      this.content = "<embed src='scripts/jwplayer/player.swf?file=" + this.href + "&autostart=true&amp;wmode=opaque' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='" + $width + "' height='" + $height + "'></embed>"; 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Which protocol are you using for streaming (RTMP, HTTP, ...)?

Comment: Does a `<div>` with id `accordion` exist in your fancybox?

Answer (score 2):

iOS only supports video streaming over the HTTP protocol, unlike Flash where you can use RTMP. A configuration example how to configure JWPlayer using a HTML5 fallback solution can be found in the [documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/18530/embedding-an-rtmp-stream-with-an-html5-fallback/).

However, you need to keep care of these lines:

```
'provider': 'rtmp',
'streamer': 'rtmp://rtmp.example.com/application',
'file': 'sintel.mp4'
```

As said, iOS only supports streaming over HTTP, so you would need something like:

```
'provider': 'http',
'streamer': 'http://rtmp.example.com/application',
'file': 'sintel.mp4'
```

Of course your streaming server must support streaming over HTTP as well.

---

**EDIT**

In order to setup your JWPlayer in fancybox you can use the methods as usual. There is nothing special using Fancybox and JWPlayer together.

HTML

```
<div class="video_popup">
    <div id="mediaplayer">Here the player will be placed</div>
</div>
```

Javascript (adapted from your question)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".video_popup").fancybox({
  fitToView: false, // to show videos in their own size
  scrolling: 'no', // don't show scrolling bars in fancybox
  afterLoad: function () {
    // get dimensions from data attributes
    var $width = $(this.element).data('width'); 
    var $height = $(this.element).data('height');

    // now, use JWPlayer to setup the player instead of embedding Flash
    jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
      // configuration code as in the documentation
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that I'm using jwplayer inside fancybox and not using the jwplayer.js to embed, so I don't get the fallback option...

Comment: So, why not using the jwplayer.js to embed the player after fancybox was opened? You will need to do this to set up the configuration appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of how I should do this?

Comment: Added example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this w4rumy...but I seem to be going backwards, fancy box is not even showing now...I have edited my OP with the code that I am now using.

Comment: Also, do I need to specify a div when I'm embedding jwplayer into fancybox?  The problem is that the content divs are generated dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

With help from w4rumy, I have managed to get jwplayer working in fancybox using html5, so plays on ipad/iphone:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jwplayer6/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".video_popup").fancybox({
  fitToView: false, 
  scrolling: 'no', 
  content: '<div id="myvideo"></div>',
  afterShow: function () {
   jwplayer('myvideo').setup({
        file: this.href,
        autostart: 'true',
         modes: [
        {type: 'flash', src: 'scripts/jwplayer6/jwplayer.flash.swf'},
        {type: 'html5', config: {file: this.href, provider: 'video'}},
    ]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: only thing is that on the ipad, autostart doesn't work as apple decided to disable this on safari...   Also, the video seems to have the overlay ontop of it and touching the play button makes fancybox go away...