# videos on ipad - iphone in a lightbox

Tags: jquery, ipad, fancybox, lightbox, jwplayer

I am after a lightbox (preferably fancybox) that can play videos with html5 on ipad, iphone.  I have tried jwplayer in fancybox but just can't get the html5 to work.  I would love to see a solution to this...

Comment: I have solved this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846926/jwplayer-in-fancybox-not-playing-on-ipad-iphone

Answer (score 0):

[jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org) also works very well with fancybox.