# fancybox + jwplayer (with html5 fallback)

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, fancybox-2, jplayer

I am trying to setup fancybox to show video. I would prefer with player but I am trying to do it with jwplayer to follow this example:
[jwplayer in fancybox not playing on ipad/iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846926/jwplayer-in-fancybox-not-playing-on-ipad-iphone)

However, I am not successful. Maybe you could help me out?

**I am loading these:**

```
  <?php echo css('assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css') ?>
  <?php echo css('assets/jplayer/skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css') ?>

  <?php echo js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js') ?>
  <?php echo js('assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js') ?>
  <?php echo js('assets/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js') ?>
  <?php echo js('assets/js/fancybox.js') ?>

  <?php echo js('assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.js') ?>
  <?php echo js('assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js') ?>
```

**In fancybox.js, I am doing this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".video_popup").fancybox({
  fitToView: false, 
  scrolling: 'no', 
  content: '<div id="myvideo"></div>',
  afterShow: function () {
   jwplayer('myvideo').setup({
        file: this.href,
        autostart: 'true',
         modes: [
        {type: 'flash', src: 'assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf'},
        {type: 'html5', config: {file: this.href, provider: 'video'}},
    ]
    });
  }
});
```

**I am calling the video like this:**

```
<a href="spline-01.mp4" class="video_popup"> here to start movie no 11</a><br><div id="myvideo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. Next: replacing jwplayer with jplayer.

```
<a class="jwVideo" spline-01.mp4" rel="group"> Preview </a>

$(function() {
    $("a.jwVideo").click(function() {
        var myVideo = this.href; // Dont forget about 'this'

        $.fancybox({
            padding : 0,
            content: '<div id="video_container">Loading the player ... </div>',
            afterShow: function(){
                jwplayer("video_container").setup({ 

                    file: myVideo,
                    width: 640,
                    height: 385,
                    modes: [
        { type: 'html5' },
        { type: 'flash', src: 'assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf' }
    ]

                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a lightbox, I would try this out instead.

https://github.com/emaxsaun/jwbox